# Selenium split date string working example?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to split a date string (04.05.2012) into 3 sub-strings for later string manipulation. When I run the below code in a regular javascript editor (in Eclipse), it works. In other words, dString[2] correctly returns 2012 . When I run the below code in Selenium IDE though, it splits the date string into 9 chars, instead of the desired 3 sub-strings.
What changes do I need to make to the below code? Or is it a bug with Selenium's implementation...?

Thanks All,
-Sam

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>04.05.2012</td>
    <td>flight_date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>dList = '${flight_date}'.split('.'); </td>
    <td>dsplit1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${dsplit1}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>day = '${dsplit1}'[9]</td>
    <td>dsplit2</td>
</tr>
<!--this returns 2-->
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${dsplit2}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>day = storedVars.dsplit1[2]</td>
    <td>dsplit2</td>
</tr>
```

instead of

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>day = '${dsplit1}'[9]</td>
    <td>dsplit2</td>
</tr>
```

it will give you a year (2012). storedVars.dsplit1[0] and storedVars.dsplit1[1] will give you 04 and 05 correspondingly. 
Or you can use simple `storeEval | dList[2] | dsplit2`. In this case you can use `getEval | dList = '${flight_date}'.split('.');` instead of  `storeEval | dList = '${flight_date}'.split('.'); | dsplit1`

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick: storeEval | dList[2] | dsplit2

Answer (score 1):

Is it treating `.` as any character as in a regular expression?

Try escaping it

```
'${flight_date}'.split('\.');
```

or

```
'${flight_date}'.split(/\./g);
```

Comment: That definitely looked promising, but that wasn't it. Thanks for the attempt.