# Is there a way to split a string into an array in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to split the string "1 out of 20"

Is there a way to store 1 in a variable and 20 in another variable?

Comment: "Please tell me how to drive 60 with my bike!" **WebDriver** is the keyword

Answer (score 1):

|store | 1 out of 20 | Text |

|storeEval | "${Text}".split(" ")[0] | firstsection |

|echo | ${firstsection} | |

[info] echo: 1

|storeEval | "${Text}".split(" ")[3] | lastsection |

|echo | ${lastsection} | |

[info] echo: 20

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this field but probbaly this coudl help you

[Selenium split date string working example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981345/selenium-split-date-string-working-example)

It looks that splitting a string is possible via Selenium