# Issue with split string in selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium. I have an issue in spliting the string.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>dList = '${StaffAdminEmail}'.split('@'); </td>
    <td>dsplit1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>day = storedVars.dsplit1[1]</td>
    <td>dsplit2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=school_permalink</td>
    <td>${dsplit2}</td>
</tr>
```

where `${StaffAdminEmail} = sample@sample.com`

I got an error like this

`[error] Threw an exception: storedVars.dsplit1 is undefined`

After google search i got a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981345/selenium-split-date-string-working-example) but i dont know how to use it with my example.Any ideas??

Comment: you not echo ${dsplit1}

Comment: I tried <td>echo$(dsplit1)</td>,but it shows as echo$(dsplit1).

Comment: problem is dsplit1 is undefined so define in your table then split

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply need to remove the whitespace after `dsplit1` in the first command

from

> ```
> <tr>
>     <td>storeEval</td>
>     <td>dList = '${StaffAdminEmail}'.split('@'); </td>
>     <td>dsplit1 </td>
> </tr>
> ```

to

> ```
> <tr>
>     <td>storeEval</td>
>     <td>dList = '${StaffAdminEmail}'.split('@'); </td>
>     <td>dsplit1</td>
> </tr>
> ```

Comment: I tried it and removing the whitespace got me past the error message you described. Didn't you get past that error message?